# How to create a dictionary from list with single for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

List is a = [1,2,3]

How to get the dictionary from that list like below?

{1: 1, 1: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 2: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 3: 2, 3: 3}

Condition is to do not use two for loops.

It was asked in an interview, but I was not able to implement without two for loops so I thought interviewer might be wrong.

Note: List a is of variable length

Comment: Consider putting your desired output `{1: 1, 1: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 2: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 3: 2, 3: 3}` into a python interpreter and printing it. What do you get? If this was an interview question, it was a trick question designed to see what you know about python dicts.

Comment: It's impossible to make this *dictionary*.

Answer (score 1):

The example that you provide would not work. As @Mark suggests, try putting the desired dictionary into an interpreter:

```
>>> {1: 1, 1: 2, 1: 3, 2: 1, 2: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 3: 2, 3: 3}
{1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3}
```

This is because, [according to Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries),

> It is best to think of a dictionary as a set of key: value pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one dictionary).

First pair creates a dictionary `{1: 1}`. Then next pair updates it: `{1: 2}`, etc. So, by the end, you will be left with the last pair with a given key (for each key).

Answer (score -1):

Cartesian product:

```
from itertools import product

a = [1,2,3]
list(product(a, a))
```

Btw, this result is not a "valid" dict because of duplicate keys.